# Can I transfer Google Search Console data along with GA4 data that is linked to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-search-console, google-analytics-4

I have Search Console data in my GA4 reports. My GA4 data is linked and transfers to BigQuery. Can Search Console data hitch a ride? Or does that have to be exported to BigQuery separately from within Search Console. Or, is it already happening and I'm bad at interpreting the transferred analytics data?

tl;dr
I've connected Search Console to GA4 and setup a transfer link to BigQuery, however the Search Console data doesn't appear to transfer over with the analytics data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at this time. The GA4 data to BigQuery is well-defined and doesn't include anything from the Search Console. You will have to export them separately and then make queries or reports that join them back together.